# Kubuntu: After login blue screen

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, laptop, amd-graphics, 21.10

I have a M6600 laptop that had a gpu chip replaced last year. In Dell's diagnostics a vga error was thrown that was gone after the repair and the laptop was doing fine.

Now when I boot the laptop the login screen seems fine but as soon as I log in the screen gets just blue. I can't switch to another tty. Only `nomodeset` helps to start kubuntu so that it is usable.

the gpu:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Blackcomb [Radeon HD 6970M/6990M] [1002:6720]
        Subsystem: Dell FirePro M8900 [1028:04a4]
```

Xorg is spitting out a lot of these:

```
[    45.052] (WW) RADEON(0): flip queue failed: Cannot allocate memory
[    45.052] (WW) RADEON(0): Page flip failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

So what is the problem? Is it the chip acting up again? I would attach the journalctl and complete xorg log but I don't know how.

Comment: Hello. Seems you need the right driver for the video chip-set. Radeon HD 6970M/6990M Common error with wrong or no driver and the fact nomodeset works just even points more to this being the issue.

Comment: @David since it was a running system for over a year: can it still be the wrong driver?

Comment: You did not say when the repair was done. Also a updated kernel may be the wrong one fro your chip set. Did you do a recent update and what is the kernel you are using? Maybe the chip set has gone bad again?

Comment: The kernel is: `5.13.0-39-generic`. I didn't do any updates before this. I updated after the error occurred though.